# parsely js : adding custom validators

Tags: parsley.js

http://parsleyjs.org/

Trying to add custom validator for image field for image resolution.

window.Parsley.addValidator

is throwing error in console as windows.parsley is undefined or null.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.ParsleyValidator.addValidator('myvalidator', 
function (value, requirement) {`enter code here`
    alert('myvalidator');
    return false;`enter code here`
}, 32)
.addMessage('en', 'myvalidator', 'my validator failed');
```

Comment: 1:1320 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addValidator' of undefined

Comment: you add all the requiment of files, i.e js file include in head block?

Comment: @NileshR: Please use `Parsley` instead of `ParsleyValidator`.
@harish: Load the library before using it...

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune Thanks for reply, Which library you mean ?  i am loading parsley.js downloaded from official parsley website, Will be great  If you could share link to library.. thanks in advance.

Comment: If `window.Parsley` is `undefined`, then clearly the `parsley` library has not loaded properly.